# Test the convergence of the sum $\sum_{n= 0 }^\infty\frac{4^{n-1}+2^n}{5^{n+1}}$

Tags: convergence-divergence

Does someone know how to evaluate the convergence of this series? I started by using the ratio test and setting $a_n = (4^{n-1}+2^n)/(5^{n+1})$, but after that step when rewriting I'm not really able to get rid of the $n$s.

Would really appreciate some help, thanks!

/Nick

Comment: the ratio test works fine.

Comment: Could you please show me how you go from there? Must have messed up something when simplifying :)

Comment: You could do a rather straightforward comparison test with $\displaystyle \sum_n \left( \frac 45 \right)^n$.

Answer (score 3):

You may also try comparison test:$$\frac{4^{n-1}+2^n}{5^{n+1}} \lt \dfrac{4^{n+1}+4^{n+1}}{5^{n+1}}=2\left(\dfrac{4}{5}\right)^{n+1}$$

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple linear combination of geometric series. We have
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^{n-1}+2^n}{5^{n+1}}=\frac{1}{20}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{4}{5})^n+\frac{1}{5}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{2}{5})^n=\frac{1}{20}\frac{1}{1-\frac{4}{5}}+\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{1-\frac{2}{5}}=\frac{7}{12}$$

Comment: Thanks! This really helped

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the ratio test, set
$$a_n=\frac{4^{n-1}+2^n}{5^{n+1}}.$$
Then
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac15\left(\frac{4^n+2^{n+1}}{4^{n-1}+2^n}\right)
=\frac45\left(\frac{1+2^{1-n}}{1+2^{2-n}}\right)\to\frac45$$
as $n\to\infty$.

So the ratio test works fine, but the other contributors' solutions are
slicker.